# Laravel: Error Code : 933 Error Message : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended Position

Tags: php, sql, oracle, laravel, laravel-4

I was trying to perform the update command as below in Laravel 4.2 using Oracle as backend.
Whenever I try to do this I get the error > ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended Position.

```
DB::statement("UPDATE APY_SUBS_DTLS_MAST SET 
    APY_SUBS_NAME=$APY_SUBS_NAME,
    APY_SUBS_FATHERS_NAME=$APY_SUBS_FATHERS_NAME,
      APY_SUBS_GENDER=$APY_SUBS_GENDER,
      APY_DATE_OF_BIRTH=to_date($APY_DATE_OF_BIRTH,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_PAN=$APY_SUBS_PAN,
      APY_SUBS_ADD=$APY_SUBS_ADD,APY_SUBS_CITY=$APY_SUBS_CITY,
      APY_SUBS_STATE=$APY_SUBS_STATE,
      APY_SUBS_CTRY=$APY_SUBS_CTRY,
      APY_SUBS_PIN=$APY_SUBS_PIN,APY_SUBS_AREA=$APY_SUBS_AREA,
      APY_LANDMARK=$APY_LANDMARK,
      APY_SUBS_TEL=$APY_SUBS_TEL,APY_SUBS_MOB=$APY_SUBS_MOB,
      APY_SUBS_MAIL=$APY_SUBS_MAIL,APY_SUBS_SMS_FLG=$APY_SUBS_SMS_FLG,
      APY_SUBS_MARITAL_STAT=$APY_SUBS_MARITAL_STAT,
      APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_NAME=$APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_NAME,
      APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_ADHAR=$APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_ADHAR,
      APY_SUBS_ACT_TYPE=$APY_SUBS_ACT_TYPE,
      APY_SUBS_BANK_NAME=$APY_SUBS_BANK_NAME,
      APY_SUBS_BRANCH=$APY_SUBS_BRANCH,APY_SUBS_MICR=$APY_SUBS_MICR,
      APY_SUBS_IFSC=$APY_SUBS_IFSC,APY_SUBS_ADHAR=$APY_SUBS_ADHAR,
      APY_SUBS_NEW_EXIST=$APY_SUBS_NEW_EXIST,
      APY_SUBS_BENEF_OTHER=$APY_SUBS_BENEF_OTHER,
      APY_SUBS_PENSION_AMT=$APY_SUBS_PENSION_AMT,APY_SUBS_CONTR_AMT=$APY_SUBS_CONTR_AMT,
      APY_SUBS_SI_DT=to_date($APY_SUBS_SI_DT,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_APLN_DATE=to_date($APY_SUBS_APLN_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_APLN_PLACE=$APY_SUBS_APLN_PLACE,
      APY_SUBS_IT_PAYER=$APY_SUBS_IT_PAYER,APY_SUBS_NOM_NAME=$APY_SUBS_NOM_NAME,
      APY_SUBS_NOM_DOB=to_date($APY_SUBS_NOM_DOB,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_NOM_ADHAR=$APY_SUBS_NOM_ADHAR,
      APY_SUBS_REL_WITH_NOM=$APY_SUBS_REL_WITH_NOM,
      APY_SUBS_MAJ_MIN_FLG=$APY_SUBS_MAJ_MIN_FLG,
      APY_SUBS_GUARD_NAME=$APY_SUBS_GUARD_NAME,
      APY_SUBS_TITLE=$APY_SUBS_TITLE 
      WHERE 
      APY_SUBS_BANK_ACT_NO=$APY_SUBS_BANK_ACT_NO;" );
```

How can I solve this, Where am I wrong?
Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: try adding ; at the end of your string

Comment: @JeremyC. I have tried, but the result is same.

Comment: have you looked at http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/queries ?

Comment: yes, but we cannot use to_date() in that.

Comment: why are you passing the date inside quotes in your to_date??? e.g. APY_DATE_OF_BIRTH=to_date('$APY_DATE_OF_BIRTH','MM-DD-YYYY')

Comment: @NithilGeorge so cast your date in your php code instead of in your update statement?

Comment: @Shankar I have tried that too, (question updated)

Comment: You are not adding the semicolon in your query. You should add it before the double quotes for the query to be complete.. It will look like  WHERE 
      APY_SUBS_BANK_ACT_NO=$APY_SUBS_BANK_ACT_NO; "

Comment: @Shankar checked that and updated the question, but same error prevails

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it. Please put every character variables in single quotes eg:-('$APY_SUBS_FATHERS_NAME'). I am giving the solution below, which may help someone.

```
DB::statement("UPDATE APY_SUBS_DTLS_MAST SET 
    APY_SUBS_NAME='$APY_SUBS_NAME',
    APY_SUBS_FATHERS_NAME='$APY_SUBS_FATHERS_NAME',
      APY_SUBS_GENDER='$APY_SUBS_GENDER',
      APY_DATE_OF_BIRTH=to_date('$APY_DATE_OF_BIRTH','MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_PAN='$APY_SUBS_PAN',
      APY_SUBS_ADD='$APY_SUBS_ADD',APY_SUBS_CITY='$APY_SUBS_CITY',
      APY_SUBS_STATE='$APY_SUBS_STATE',
      APY_SUBS_CTRY='$APY_SUBS_CTRY',
      APY_SUBS_PIN='$APY_SUBS_PIN',APY_SUBS_AREA='$APY_SUBS_AREA',
      APY_LANDMARK='$APY_LANDMARK',
      APY_SUBS_TEL=$APY_SUBS_TEL,APY_SUBS_MOB=$APY_SUBS_MOB,
      APY_SUBS_MAIL='$APY_SUBS_MAIL',APY_SUBS_SMS_FLG='$APY_SUBS_SMS_FLG',
      APY_SUBS_MARITAL_STAT='$APY_SUBS_MARITAL_STAT',
      APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_NAME='$APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_NAME',
      APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_ADHAR='$APY_SUBS_SPOUSE_ADHAR',
      APY_SUBS_ACT_TYPE='$APY_SUBS_ACT_TYPE',
      APY_SUBS_BANK_NAME='$APY_SUBS_BANK_NAME',
      APY_SUBS_BRANCH='$APY_SUBS_BRANCH',APY_SUBS_MICR=$APY_SUBS_MICR,
      APY_SUBS_IFSC='$APY_SUBS_IFSC',APY_SUBS_ADHAR='$APY_SUBS_ADHAR',
      APY_SUBS_NEW_EXIST='$APY_SUBS_NEW_EXIST',
      APY_SUBS_BENEF_OTHER='$APY_SUBS_BENEF_OTHER',
      APY_SUBS_PENSION_AMT=$APY_SUBS_PENSION_AMT,APY_SUBS_CONTR_AMT=$APY_SUBS_CONTR_AMT,
      APY_SUBS_SI_DT=to_date('$APY_SUBS_SI_DT','MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_APLN_DATE=to_date('$APY_SUBS_APLN_DATE','MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_APLN_PLACE='$APY_SUBS_APLN_PLACE',
      APY_SUBS_IT_PAYER='$APY_SUBS_IT_PAYER',APY_SUBS_NOM_NAME='$APY_SUBS_NOM_NAME',
      APY_SUBS_NOM_DOB=to_date('$APY_SUBS_NOM_DOB','MM-DD-YYYY'),
      APY_SUBS_NOM_ADHAR='$APY_SUBS_NOM_ADHAR',
      APY_SUBS_REL_WITH_NOM='$APY_SUBS_REL_WITH_NOM',
      APY_SUBS_MAJ_MIN_FLG='$APY_SUBS_MAJ_MIN_FLG',
      APY_SUBS_GUARD_NAME='$APY_SUBS_GUARD_NAME',
      APY_SUBS_TITLE='$APY_SUBS_TITLE' 
      WHERE 
      APY_SUBS_BANK_ACT_NO='$APY_SUBS_BANK_ACT_NO'" );
```